# Squash commits after merging upstream branch

Tags: git

In my feature branch the history looks something like

branch from master -> add commits -> merge latest commits on master -> add more commits

In the 'add commits' section some large files were added which were then deleted in 'add more commits'. I would like to squash a few of the commits from the first and second set of commits on the feature branch to free this space. Unfortunately it seems the merge from master will make this difficult.

This seems to be different to the other questions similar to this because the 2 branches are still separate but I simply merged in the latest commits from master. The feature branch is only used by me so I can rewrite the history on it.

Comment: Squash first and merge *again*.

Comment: See the comment by @iBug above.  You will probably have to redo the merge(s).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to draw your scenario to make it easier to talk about:

```
      master
      v
A--B--C
 \     \
  D--E--M--F--G
              ^
              feature
```

Now, let's assume for the sake of argument that you want to squash commit `G` (which happened *after* the merge) into commit `E` (which happened *before* the merge).

As [@iBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5958455/ibug) pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472022/squash-commits-after-merging-upstream-branch#comment101416354_57472022), the easiest way out―since you own the branch―is to simply do the squash and then redo the merge, since by default the interactive rebase will drop any merge commits in the selected range.

However, if you really want to keep `M` where it is, you can try to do an iteractive rebase with the [`--rebase-merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins) option:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i --rebase-merges D
```

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins):

> With `--rebase-merges`, the rebase will instead try to preserve the branching structure within the commits that are to be rebased, by recreating the merge commits.

However, keep in mind that:

> Any resolved merge conflicts or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be resolved/re-applied manually.

So, the only thing that `--rebase-merges` buys you in this case is that the merge commit stays in the same position in the history of the `feature` branch after you've squashed the commits.